# Multiple calculations on the same big.Int in one line

Tags: go, solidity

I have the below code in Solidity which calculates the value of `denominator` variable in one line.

```
uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(997);
uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
```

In my Go code, I couldn't figure out how to do the same, therefore I have done it in two lines with a solution that might create false results compared to the Solidity code.

```
amountInWithFee := big.NewInt(0).Mul(amountIn, fee)
denominator0 := big.NewInt(0).Mul(reserveIn, amount1K)
denominator := big.NewInt(0).Add(denominator0, amountInWithFee)
```

My question is that does my Go implementation do the same as the Solidity version? Is it possible to achive the same calculation in one line of Golang code? I followed some `big.Int` related answers from here, but I am new to the language so it can happen that I made my mistake somewhere.

[Go Playground with full code is here](https://go.dev/play/p/FBcYN2bJHV-).

Comment: Why do you think having a code in one line is _efficient_?

Comment: `Mul` and `Add` return `*Float` so you should be able to chain the method calls.  Include a complete, minimal example (as always you should - maybe with go playground?) and we'll help you figure out how.

Comment: You can simply substitute the expressions for the variable names and make this one line, but there's no real reason to do that. The only way to make it more efficient would be to reuse the values which can be mutated to avoid allocations, but we don't have enough context to determine what that might be.

Comment: @Inian I am not certain in it because I am unfamiliar with Go. It felt strange compared to a Python or Solidty implementation for instance which makes it in one line. This is why I'd like to know if there is a better one liner solution or this current one is good as it is.

Comment: @DanielFarrell it does not return a float https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Mul, it is returning an int because it uses the big package - I have added the Go Playground link with the working code.

Comment: @JimB I added a go playground link for the full context.

Comment: @rihe: writing that on one line would look ridiculous. If you want to reduce allocations then reuse the values which allows some chaining: https://go.dev/play/p/_Td00jnBPxv

Comment: @JimB This is better as you did.